# I want to insert Text in special position only in Line 5

Tags: text, sed, insert, position

I have a Text file . In this Text File I want only at Line 5 the word "hello world" geting insertet starting at position 10 and output the file.

Anybody has an Idea? thanks very much.

Sorry i have no Idea ......

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '5s/./hello world&/10' file
```

on line 5 only and at position 10 character from the start of the line, insert the string `hello world`.

N.B. To make these changes permanent for `file` use the option `-i`

```
sed -i '5s/./hello world&/10' file
```

Comment: tkanks but its noth working , iam working with cygwin and on my script this not works